# SQL summarise based on condition

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate, summarize

Let's say I have a table called `Table1` that contains three columns, `VALUE`, `CODE` and `TYPE`. The column `VALUE` contains scores ranging from 1-4 for different questions. The column `CODE` contains the code pertaining to the question. The column `TYPE` indicates whether the question is part of a paper (PAP) or online (ONL) survey.

Here's a glimpse of what the table looks like.

```
#Table1

VALUE    CODE    TYPE
-----   ------  ------ 
  2      Q2      ONL 
  1      Q2      PAP
  3      Q2      ONL
  4      Q2      ONL
  1      Q2      ONL
  1      Q2      ONL
  1      Q2      PAP
  2      Q2      ONL
  4      Q2      ONL
  2      Q2      ONL
  3      Q1      ONL
  1      Q1      ONL
  4      Q1      ONL
  3      Q1      ONL
      and so on...
```

**My Objective**

To summarize this table using an SQL query (Oracle) such that-

1) *I first **count** all values that are either **1's** OR **2's*** for `CODE` **Q2**

2) *And divide that number by the **total** number of values for Q2*

3) Group results by `TYPE` so that I have grouped results for both **ONL** and **PAP**.

**Intended Outcome**

So in our case, the result of this query would be -

```
TYPE      SCORE
PAP       0.625 (5/8)
ONL       1     (2/2)
```

**My Attempt**

As simple as this seems, I cannot seem to get the right value. I feel this requires a nested query to store the different values but I am unable to find the right example to guide me. Here's my incorrect attempt at it-

```
SELECT TYPE, VALUE/COUNT(VALUE) as SCORE FROM Table1
where
CODE = 'Q2' AND
VALUE in (1,2)
GROUP BY TYPE
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the output you got?

Comment: providing create and insert statement will help

Comment: Are the numbers in your expected output attached to the wrong type? Shouldn't it be `PAP 1`, `ONL 0.625`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several ways to do this.
The problem with your query is that you didn't execute step two - getting the TOTAL number of responses for Q2.

Here's my SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/898b3f/7

```
SELECT TYPE, 
COUNT(VALUE), 
(select count(*) from table1 where code = 'Q2') ,
COUNT(VALUE) / (select count(*) from table1 where code = 'Q2') as score
FROM Table1
where
CODE = 'Q2' AND
VALUE in (1,2)
GROUP BY TYPE
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do:

```
select type, avg(case when value in (1, 2) then 1.0 else 0 end) 
from table1
where code = 'Q2'
group by type;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
select type, cnt_value/sum_value as score 
 FROM (
  SELECT type, count (value) as cnt_value , sum (value) as sum_value 
    FROM Table1
   WHERE
    CODE = 'Q2' AND
   VALUE in (1,2)
   GROUP by type
)
```